# Automated script install using bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to script install the below, how can I answer "y" at the prompt within the command

```
 wget -O - mic.raspiaudio.com | sudo bash
```

I have tried the usual but this wont work

```
echo "y" |  wget -O - mic.raspiaudio.com | sudo bash
```

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://askubuntu.com/a/805324/132233

Comment: Running scripts directly from remote source is a considerable security risk, especially amplified by using the root account. See: https://github.com/sethgrid/exploit. Always prefer downloading, reviewing and running separately. see also: https://www.idontplaydarts.com/images/bashmov.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: The solution below works for script that have a non-interactive switch.

I believe the `echo` won't work on this because it's not writing to the `/dev/tty` that the `bash` spawned. You can do it using the default feature `bash` provides.

From the man page:

```
-c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first 
          non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the
          command_string,  the  first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining
          arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.
```

If you use `-c` option with bash, you can supply args to script that will run and those will be placed as mentioned in the man page. eg:
`bash -c "script" "arg0" "arg1" ...`. The `arg0` will be placed in `$0` and `arg1` will be placed in `$1` and so on.

Now, I don't know if this can be generalized, but this solution will only work if there is a non-interactive mode in the script.

If you see the script it has the following function:

```
FORCE=$1

confirm() {
    if [ "$FORCE" == '-y' ]; then
        true
    else
        read -r -p "$1 [y/N] " response < /dev/tty
        if [[ $response =~ ^(yes|y|Y)$ ]]; then
            true
        else
            false
        fi
    fi
}
```

And is used as :

```
if confirm "Do you wish to continue"
then
  echo "You are good to go"
fi
```

So, if we can set the $1 to "-y" it won't ask for a confirmation, We will try to do that same by:

```
$ bash -c "$( wget -qO - mic.raspiaudio.com)" "dummy" "-y"
```

This should work for the script, provided it does not have any other interactive options. I have not tested the original script by my own minimal script and it seems to work. eg:

```
$ bash -c "$(wget -qO - localhost:8080/test.sh)" "dummy" -y
You are good to go
```

```
$ bash -c "$(wget -qO - localhost:8080/test.sh)"
Do you wish to continue [y/N] y
You are good to go
```